# OCaml compile classes that depend on each other

Tags: ocaml, circular-dependency

Let's say I have two classes called A (parent) and B (child). A stores a list of B objects and B stores a variable containing a single instance of an A object.

As far as I know, OCaml requires the classes to be specified in a certain order based on their dependencies (i.e. if C depends on D, you need to compile the code like the following: `ocamlopt -o main D.ml C.ml`)

Since the classes A and B depend so closely on each other, how can we compile the two classes together?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define the two classes in the same source file, using `and` to make them recursively defined.

```
# class a = object val my_b_list : b list = [] end
  and b = object val my_a : a = new a end;;
class a : object val my_b_list : b list end
and b : object val my_a : a end
```

If you need to define them in separate files, you can parameterize one of them by the type of the other. This is more complicated.